# Auto format arguments to string

Tags: python

I am writing a function that takes some arguments and builds a SQL query string.  I currently have each of the keyword arguments assigned to the string by name, and I am thinking that there has to be an easier way to automatically format the keyword arguments expected in the string.  I'm wondering if it is possible to automatically format (or assign) a keyword argument to the query string if the argument name matches.

Here is my current function:

```
def create_query(
    who_id,
    what_id=None,
    owner_id=None,
    subject,
    description,
    due_date,
    is_closed=False,
    is_priority=False,
    is_reminder=True,
    ):

    query_str = """
        'WhoId':'{who_id}',
        'Subject':'{subject}',
        'Description':'{description}',
        'ActivityDate':'{due_date}',
        'IsClosed':'{is_closed}',
        'IsPriority':'{is_priority}',
        'IsReminderSet':'{is_reminder}',
        """.format(
            who_id=who_id,
            subject=subject,               # Mapping each of these to the
            description=description,       # identically named variable
            due_date=due_date,             # seems dumb
            is_closed=is_closed,
            is_priority=is_priority,
            is_reminder=is_reminder,
            )
```

And I would like something that is more like this:

```
def create_query(**kwargs):
    query_string = """
         'WhoId':'{who_id}',
         'Subject':'{subject}',
         'Description':'{description}',
         ...
         """.format(
             for key in **kwargs:
                 if key == << one of the {keyword} variables in query_string >>:
                     key = << the matching variable in query_string >>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create_query(**kwargs):
    query_string = """
         'WhoId':'{who_id}',
         'Subject':'{subject}',
         'Description':'{description}',
         ...
         """.format(**kwargs)
    print(query_string)
```

Can be used like this then:

```
create_query(who_id=123, subject="Boss", description="he's bossy",
             will_be_ignored="really?")
```

Prints:

```
         'WhoId':'123',
         'Subject':'Boss',
         'Description':'he is bossy',
         ...
```

Note the additional parameter `will_be_ignored` that I entered. It will simply be ignored. You don't have to filter that yourself.

But better don't build the query string yourself. Let the database connector handle that. For example, if my example said "he's bossy" then that would break the query because it uses `'` as delimiter. Your database connector should allow you to give it queries with placeholders and values, and then properly replace the placeholders with the values.

Alternative:

```
def create_query(**kwargs):
    parameters = (('WhoId', 'who_id'),
                  ('Subject','subject'),
                  ('Description', 'description'))
    query_string = ','.join(r"'{}':'{{{}}}'".format(name, kwargs[id])
                            for name, id in parameters
                            if id in kwargs)
    print(query_string)

create_query(who_id=123, description="he's bossy",
             will_be_ignored="really?")
```

Prints:

```
'WhoId':'{123}','Description':'{he's bossy}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  How do you recommend handling optional kwargs?   For example, there are certain items that may not be relevant to the query, but I want to provide an option to build them into the query.  In this example, if I did not pass a value for Description, there would be a key error.  Agreed that this it is not optimal to build the query string but I am working with the Salesforce API, so I'm not sure how else to handle this other than sanitizing for quotes and double quotes.

Comment: @JoeFusaro You mean you want default values then, or you don't want them in the final query string at all?

Comment: Preference would be that they are not in the final query string at all, but default values are OK.  Not sure what is optimal.  I thought about concatenation based on if they are included in kwargs (ex. if kwargs['description']:  query_string += """, 'Description':'{description}'..... ) but that seems messy.

Comment: @JoeFusaro At that point you better don't write the format string as such. Have a look at the "Alternative" I just added to my answer.